Deploy C# Executable to GCP Cloud Functions
Can I deploy a C# executable to GCP Cloud Functions and, therefore, bypass Cloud Functions' source code build process?
I'd like to deploy my compiled C# executable to GCP Cloud Functions, but it appears Cloud Functions requires me to provide my uncompiled source code and it will build a container from it to run on Cloud Functions.
I think the problem is that my project structure is nested - with the entry point's project having a dependency on a project higher up in the project structure, which I don't think plays well with the project structure that Cloud Functions seems to expect.
This could be solved if I built the executable in my CICD pipeline and Cloud Functions just allowed me to deploy the executable to the service.  However, I've not found anything that says this is possible for C# and Cloud Functions (it is possible for Java, though).

Why don't you instead use Cloud Run and build a container with your executable?

I'd like to avoid having to use containers.


Can I deploy a C# executable to GCP Cloud Functions and, therefore, bypass Cloud Functions' source code build process?

Not at the moment, no. There's a Buildpack feature request for it, but I wouldn't hold my breath.
Personally in this situation I'd probably look into packaging it up as an image and deploying directly to Cloud Run.
However, if the aim isn't really "deploy a binary" so much as "deploy my project" as per this:

I think the problem is that my project structure is nested - with the entry point's project having a dependency on a project higher up in the project structure, which I don't think plays well with the project structure that Cloud Functions seems to expect.

... then we do have a way of handling that, as documented in "Deploying a function with a local project dependency" with an example.
Basically, you deploy from the root directory (potentially with a .gcloudignore file) so that all the required source code is uploaded, and then use --set-build-env-vars to set the GOOGLE_BUILDABLE environment variable in the Buildpack, which then specifies the project that contains your function.
The example in the Functions Framework repo is deployed as:
gcloud functions deploy multi-project \
  --runtime dotnet6 \
  --trigger-http \
  --entry-point=Google.Cloud.Functions.Examples.MultiProjectFunction.Function \
  --set-build-env-vars=GOOGLE_BUILDABLE=Google.Cloud.Functions.Examples.MultiProjectFunction


I tested this and found that it did work!  Thank you!
A note to anyone else trying this:  GOOGLE_BUILDABLE is a relative directory path, not the C# namespace, which isn't clear in the GitHub sample project but is clear in the GCP documentation:  https://cloud.google.com/docs/buildpacks/service-specific-configs#google_buildable.  So, I used --set-build-env-vars=GOOGLE_BUILDABLE=./path/to/my/project.

@jones-chris: Thanks for the feedback, I'll update the deployment docs to clarify that.
